# Write to file but not erase

Tags: php

I have a function to write to a .txt file. my problem is that it writes only on the first line, so erases the old line for the new line. I want to append the new lines to the file.

```
    function logit($log,$filename = ''){
        $logfile = "log/".date('Ymd').$filename.".txt";
        if ($fh = fopen($logfile, 'w')) {
            fwrite($fh, date('H:i:s')." | ".$log."\n");
            fclose($fh);
            return 1;   
        } else
            return false;
     }
```

Comment: Just a workaround, even though I'm pretty sure there is a way to write from last line: instead of opening the file and writing the content, open the file, copy the current file content, append to it what you want to add and write the whole thing :). If I'm not wrong, anyway, instead of using this workaround, you may simply use fopen($logfile,'a') instead of 'w'. -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: Have you RTFM for [`fopen`](http://php.net/fopen)?

Comment: Yes, but i was confused..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to search before post your question.. there's many documentation and answers for that problem.. anyway, replace this `fopen($logfile, 'w')` with `fopen($logfile, 'a')`